# export import <name> syntax in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

While browsing [a declaration file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/passport-github/index.d.ts) on `dt` I came accross the following syntax:

```js
import github = Strategy; // <- what is imported from where here?

declare class Strategy extends oauth2.Strategy {
     ...
}

declare namespace Strategy {
    export import Strategy = github; // <- I've not seen this syntax before?

    interface _StrategyOptionsBase {
      ...
    }
}

export = Strategy;
```

I'm having trouble understanding the import and export syntax here. I roughly understand typescripts `export=` [custom syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require). However, I don't understand why and what we're exporting from the namespace. Nor do I fully understand what we're importing with `import github ...`.

I'd love some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
import github = Strategy;
```

this syntax describes a namespace alias.

> Another way that you can simplify working with namespaces is to use `import q = x.y.z` to create shorter names for commonly-used objects.
>
> ```js
> namespace Shapes {
>   export namespace Polygons {
>     export class Triangle {}
>     export class Square {}
>   }
> }
> import polygons = Shapes.Polygons;
> let sq = new polygons.Square(); // Same as 'new Shapes.Polygons.Square()'
> ```

[source](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#aliases)

---

```js
export import Strategy = github
```

is a combination of renaming the namespace and exporting it again with the new
name. You can't write something like

```
declare namespace Strategy {
    export namespace Strategy;
}
```

so this looks like a workaround to achieve what is done in the
`passport-github` source code.

```js
// Load modules.
var Strategy = require('./strategy');

// Expose Strategy.
exports = module.exports = Strategy;

// Exports.
exports.Strategy = Strategy;
```

[source](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-github/blob/master/lib/index.js)

```js
exports = module.exports = Strategy;
```

this line exports `Strategy` as default export, the counterpart in the
typescript definition is

```js
export = Strategy
```

Then passport-gitlab also export `Strategy` as property on the default export.

```
exports.Strategy = Strategy;
```

You can think of it like a class that has a static property which references
the class.

```
class Strategy {
    static Strategy: typeof Strategy
}
export = Strategy
```